# HTTP Error 404.3 Not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs, iis, visual-studio-2013

I am going through [this](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05) tutorial. 
I have this setup as an MVC4 project. This is the first project I made using Vs 2013.

I am on the step when I collect the json from phones.json. I get the error.

```
HTTP Error 404.3 -Not found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of extension configuration.
If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.
```

Also here is my call to the json file

```
$http.get('Data/Phones/phones.json').success(function (data) {
     $scope.phones = data;
})
```

and here is an image of my folder structure

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add this to the project's web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: 10X vm =) do you know why we need to add that?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.It helped me a lot to resolve the issue  that I was facing :)